# DNS failure every few minutes in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: networking, dns

Every few minutes, when I request a web page, I get a DNS lookup failure. Usually, if I just immediately refresh, the web page will come up. However, recently the DNS failures have been persisting for long periods of time, even across restarts (though eventually, it always starts working again, at least for a while). It happens in Chrome, Firefox, Thunderbird, and Update Manager. When this happens, if I ping a host name like www.google.com, I get an unknown host message, but if I ping an IP address, it works fine.

I'm also running Windows 7 in a VMWare virtual machine on the Ubuntu host, and if I switch to the VM, I have no problems, even when the host Ubuntu is having DNS failures.

Note, I'm using a wired ethernet connection.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Comment out the line that says `dns=dnsmasq`

[image]

Once done, restart network Manager

```
sudo restart network-manager
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll give this a try and report back if it works. Are there any negative consequences to commenting out the `dns=dnsmasq` line? Why does that cause these intermittent failures? Has a bug been filed about this?

Comment: No negative consequences.  Once you try it, will go from there.

Comment: Well, no further problems so far, so I'm cautiously optimistic that this is the solution. Still, it seems like this should be considered a bug, no?